# how to get Unique records from elastic search engine based on a field

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index that stores the list of restaurants in an area. I'm using spring elastic search to query the restaurant based on a given geo-location (lat/long) within 10 miles distance. I have a requirement where I only need to show a restaurant chain once, I'm seeing multiple records in my search result for the restaurant chains because they have the same name but different addresses. I only need to show the nearest restaurant chain restaurant along with the other unique restaurants. Is there a single query that can do that? Below is my code [removed some stuff for brevity!]

```
public SearchHits<Results> search(List<String> items){
final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
 BoolQueryBuilder termsQuery = boolQuery();
 termsQuery.should(termsQuery(entry.getKey(), items));
 boolQuery.must(termsQuery);
 // ...I do additional logic here
 searchQuery.withQuery(boolQuery);
 // apply the terms aggregation searchQuery.addAggregation(terms(CATEGORIES_KEY).field(CATEGORY).size(BUCKET_SIZE));
 Query query = searchQuery.build();
 SearchHits<Results> searchHits = elasticsearcTemplate.search(query, Results.class);
return searchHits;
}
```

Comment: Provide more details please, are you using geolocation to locate the restaurants?

Comment: yes, @rabbitbr I am using geo query to get the restaurant list 10 miles distance from the given lat/long.

Comment: You can use terms aggregation on the context payload post search on geo-location based on restaurant/ chain name whatever field contains the name, and then access this list in your application.

Comment: Hi, @Ayush I didn't understand what you're suggesting, Can you please give a JSON query or java code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going thru the documentation of elasticsearch, it turns out...there is a simple fix for that :) I can use [Collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) The collapse feature removes the duplicate data based on a field. So I only needed to add this line:

```
searchQuery.withCollapseField("restaurant_name"); 
// restaurant_name is what I want unique values on
```